# W5500 reference design doesn't work with short Ethernet cables

Tags: ethernet

This issue is similar to [W5500 network configuration issues](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/528701/w5500-network-configuration-issues) (also unresolved) but not the same.

I have used the reference design (followed to the letter) for the Wiznet W5500 Ethernet controller on about 100 boards to date, across 15 projects. These are on boards with microcontrollers of different makes and models, some PoE, and they all work.. unless you use a short Ethernet cable (≤ 10 m or so). If you use a short cable, the Ethernet controller fails to initialize.

I use Cisco SG350 switches, and the workaround I've found is to get into the port settings on these switches and untick 'Auto Negotiation' and force the speed to 100M Full Duplex. Then it'll work, regardless the cable length.

But on a longer cable, I never have to do that. The negotiation just works. I'm sorry to say I haven't tested it with more switches - We only have lots of SG350s here.

My only theory so far is this: There are four 33R resistors inline with the TX/RX pins on the cable side of the controller. I wonder if these are too weak and I need to pad these back further? I fear that that may then lower the performance for longer cables.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting! Do you have an oscilloscope fast enough to compare negotiation on long and short cables?

Comment: The capacitors in series with data pair seem awfully low in value. Another manufacturer says that for capacitive coupled links without a transformer the capacitance should be much higher and still they recommend turning off the autonegotiation as the FLP pulse parameters can't be guaranteed. But it might be something else. Can you provide your schematic or at least point to which exact eval board you cloned?

Comment: The 6.8nF capacitors on the Rx lines? Interesting. I didn't clone an eval board (that might've helped!), the schematic I followed is: [link](http://wizwiki.net/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php/wiznet_schematic:ethernet_chip:w5500_sch_v110_use_mag_.pdf) but with the 33R damping resistors installed.

Comment: @Justme I tried changing those capacitors to a few different values. 10nF worked on a short cable but took a long time to come up. 100nF didn't work on a short cable at all. 22nF seems to work quite well. Still doesn't come up as fast as on a longer cable (can take 10-20 seconds), but seems to work consistently at least. I'm going to try it with a 0R resistor network instead of the 33R resistor network (recommended for EMI) next, some folks over on the Wiznet forum rate that.